# Не могу написать python код но написал на С++ нужна помощь перевести с С++ на python

Tags: python, c++

Дана матрица A[m×n]. Напишите программу, которая сортирует
элементы каждой строки по возрастанию. Используйте сортировку вставками
(Insertion sort).

```
  #include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m; // вводим количество столбцов и строк через пробел
    int array[n][m];
 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cin >> array[i][j]; // вводим элементы в массив
        }
    }
 
    // теперь всё это дело сортируем пузырьком
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < m; o++)
            {
                if (array[i][o] > array[i][o + 1])
                {
                    int tmp = array[i][o];
                    array[i][o] = array[i][o + 1];
                    array[i][o + 1] = tmp;
                }
 
            }
        }
    }
    
    // ну и выводим на экран что получилось
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
 
    retur
```

n 0;
}

Comment: В задании говорится о сортировке вставками,  а в коде почему-то пузырек

Answer (score 2):

Пузырек

```
def matrix_sort(matrix):
    m = len(matrix)
    n = len(matrix[0])

    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n-1):
            for k in range(n-i-1):
                if matrix[i][k] > matrix[i][k+1]:
                    matrix[i][k], matrix[i][k+1] = matrix[i][k+1], matrix[i][k]

    return matrix


a = [[2, 4, 1, 5], [6, 4, 2, 7]]
print(matrix_sort(a))
```

Вставки

```
def matrix_sort(matrix):
    m = len(matrix)
    n = len(matrix[0])

    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(1, n):
            item_to_insert = matrix[i][j]
            k = j - 1
            
            while k >= 0 and matrix[i][k] > item_to_insert:
                matrix[i][k + 1] = matrix[i][k]
                k -= 1

            matrix[i][k + 1] = item_to_insert

    return matrix


a = [[2, 4, 1, 5], [6, 4, 2, 7]]
print(matrix_sort(a))
```

Вывод настройте под себя.

А вообще очень нехорошо просить просто переписать код. Хоть написали бы, что конкретно не понятно и не получается.

Comment: В коде он писал пузырьком, я и адаптировал его C++ код

Comment: ОК, хорошо получилось.